# Train NER SpaCy using en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg model

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am currently working on NER project and I would like to improve my NER performance by trying new SpaCy model `en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg` but it gave me error `KeyError: "[E001] No component 'trf_tok2vec' found in pipeline. Available names: ['ner']"`. Is it that SpaCy currently does not support NER for this language model? Thanks!

```
   # get names of other pipes to disable them during training
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
        for itn in tqdm(range(n_iter)):
            random.shuffle(train_data_list)
            losses = {}
            # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
            batches = minibatch(train_data_list, size=compounding(8., 64., 1.001))
            for batch in batches:
                texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
                nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35,
                           losses=losses)
            tqdm.write('Iter: ' + str(itn + 1) + ' Losses: ' + str(losses['ner']))
            if itn == 30 or itn == 40:
                output_dir = Path(output_dir)
                if not output_dir.exists():
                    output_dir.mkdir()
                nlp.to_disk(Path(output_dir))
```

It gave error on

```
nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.35,
                           losses=losses)
```

Comment: Could you post the code that caused the error?

Comment: I added the code snippet on my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of this model on spaCy [here](https://spacy.io/models/en#en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg), this model doesn't support Named-Entity Recognition yet. It only supports:

- `sentencizer`
- `trf_wordpiecer`
- `trf_tok2vec`

You can get the available pipe for a given model like so:

```
>>> import spacy

>>> nlp = spacy.load("en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg")
>>> nlp.pipe_names
[sentencizer, trf_wordpiecer, trf_tok2vec]
```